# Ingress-nginx default-backend to catch error produced only by controller itsefl not app

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I use nginx ingress inside aws eks kubernetes cluster to serve [content](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/).
Nginx ingress have [defaut-backend](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/default-backend/) functional which handles all URL paths and hosts the Ingress-NGINX controller doesn't understand.

I use helm [chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx) to deploy ingress and I enable default backend with defaultBackend.enabled=true .

By default it works and shows error page when I request any domain pointed to balancer but not associated with ingress. It works only this way and shows me 404 error.
As I said above I want to display custom error page on another codes too (like 403 when limited by `whitelist-source-range`, 502 and 503 produced by controller, etc.).

According to [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/custom-errors) I added `custom-http-errors` parameter to configmap. (`custom-http-errors: 403, 404, 429, 503, 502`).
**Now it shows error pages on ingress error as expected but it also replaces pages that comes from upstream.**

It replaces 404 page that comes from frontend or api.
It replaces 403 code from jenkins so users are not redirected to login page.
it replaces 503 code from api with additional info.

I need to catch error probuced by ingress controller itself not app.

I have tried to find way to replace default static pages but seems like they are hardcoded inside nginx.
I also tried to customize ingress with config snippets but nothing seem to work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this behavior came from vanilla NGINX and can be managed by [proxy_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) parameter in config that says to nginx  whether proxied responses with codes greater than or equal to 300 should be passed to a client or be intercepted and redirected to nginx for processing with the error_page directive.

Currently nginx-ingress activates this parameter when [custom-http-errors](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#custom-http-errors) enabled. According to [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#custom-http-errors) :
Setting at least one code also enables proxy_intercept_errors which are required to process error_page.

I found [pull request](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/9497) that adds separate option for proxy_intercept_errors parameter so we just need it to be merged.